# Which Intent type does an empty NFC tag fall into?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm having trouble matching which `Intent` filter to use for an empty NFC tag. I am able to detect tags with NDEF data. But when I tap on an empty NFC tag nothing happens.

Below is the filter part in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

Comment: Hmmm... your `TECH_DISCOVERED` and `TAG_DISCOVERED` should be covering it. Leastways, that is what NFCTagInfo uses, and I seem to recall that they detect unformatted tags (which I presume is your definition of "empty").

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying to look for a way to detect unformatted or "empty" tags since I will be handling them in a write method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that doing the following in my nfc tech filter list:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

was not matching any of my tags because they are evaluated as logical AND. To get my app to match my NFC tags I just created a specific tag tech-list for my tags like so:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>        
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

This will match the tags as `(NfcA AND Ndef AND MifareUltralight) OR NfcA OR Ndef OR MifareUltralight`. Hope this helps anyone who's currently stuck with this problem.

Comment: You could simplify this to just a tech-list for NfcA (which includes MifareUltralight) and one for Ndef.

Comment: Thank you for this, got it working in 2 minutes. Where were you guys the other day when I wasted _hours_ not getting this working?

Answer (score 3):

You should add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` to the TECH_DISOVERED (and TAG_DISCOVERED) filter. Otherwise it will not match.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I found the real problem behind this - I found out that the `tech-list` are given AND logic.